# Laravel: Filter while querying a DB or after the query?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a JS developer but trying to help out my team with some Laravel.
I have his query below:

```
$customers = ShopUser::selectRaw('shop_users.name, shop_users.email, shop_users.unique_id, shop_users.created_at, SUM(orders.total) AS total_spent, MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_purchase, MAX(orders.created_at) AS last_purchase, count(orders.id) AS total_orders')
            ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.customer_id', 'shop_users.id')
            ->groupBy('shop_users.id')
            ->get();
```

I want to then put the `unique_id` of users of this query who have a `total` over $1,000 spent in an array.  Is there a way to do that in the query above or should I make a separate iteration after this to sort that?

Comment: Do you want the result of this query and list of users who have spent more than $1000? or just want the unique_id of users who have spent more than $1000.

Comment: @JitendraYadav all I need is a list of `unique_id`s that have a `total` over 1,000.   Ex: `[233123, 434341, 35545123]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use use `havingRaw`

```
ShopUser::selectRaw('shop_users.name, shop_users.email, shop_users.unique_id, shop_users.created_at, SUM(orders.total) AS total_spent, MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_purchase, MAX(orders.created_at) AS last_purchase, count(orders.id) AS total_orders')
            ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.customer_id', 'shop_users.id')
            ->havingRaw('total_spent > ?', [1000])
            ->groupBy('shop_users.id')
            ->get();
```

If you want to return the result as an array, you can use `pluck`

```
ShopUser::selectRaw('shop_users.name, shop_users.email, shop_users.unique_id, shop_users.created_at, SUM(orders.total) AS total_spent, MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_purchase, MAX(orders.created_at) AS last_purchase, count(orders.id) AS total_orders')
            ->leftJoin('orders', 'orders.customer_id', 'shop_users.id')
            ->havingRaw('total_spent > ?', [1000])
            ->groupBy('shop_users.id')
            ->get()
            ->pluck('unique_id')
            ->all()
```

I haven't tested it, but I hope this helps

Comment: this is perfect but even using `pluck` to grab the `unique_id`, it returns an Object:  The result is: 
 `Object {0: "2091844024194348"}`

Comment: that makes it an array of objects . `[ {0: "2091844024194348"} ]`

Comment: replace the pluck with just `->get()->pluck('unique_id')->all()`

Comment: thanks Jonas ! still gives me `[ {0: "2091844024194348"} ]` tthough`

Comment: Is this array you're showing me rendered in backend (PHP) or frontend (Javascript)? I created a query similar to yours and just returned the array of values.

Comment: yep, rendered in the backend,  I'm logging it rightt after the query

Comment: Yeah! but what was the problem?

Comment: just how I was logging it -- it was in the correct format with your code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are lot of approaches to achieve this goal in Laravel, I prefer the **Eloquent Query Builder** approach rather than **Row Queries**.

I assume that all you need is a list of unique ids that have a total over 1,000. Ex: [233123, 434341, 35545123].

So any other selections, groupings and filters you have written in your code is ignored.

```php
&shopUserIds = ShopUser::whereHas('orders', function ($query) {
                   $query->where(DB::row('SUM(total)'), '>', '1000');
               })
               ->get()
               ->map->id
               ->toArray();
```